# Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex and Pagination issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

***I speak English not well, so sorry.***

The code.

routers.ini:

```
routes.cat1.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.cat1.route = "showcat/(\d+)-(\d+)"
routes.cat1.defaults.module = "default"
routes.cat1.defaults.controller = "category"
routes.cat1.defaults.action = "viewcategory"
routes.cat1.map.1 = "id1"
routes.cat1.map.2 = "page"
routes.cat1.reverse = "showcat/%d-%d"
```

When i visit:

```
showcat/6
```

It returns error: **Invalid controller specified (showcat)**

But when i visit:

```
showcat/6-1
```

It works fine.

When i add following router to fix above problem:

```
routes.cat2.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.cat2.route = "showcat/(\d+)"
routes.cat2.defaults.module = "default"
routes.cat2.defaults.controller = "category"
routes.cat2.defaults.action = "viewcategory"
routes.cat2.map.1 = "id1"
routes.cat2.reverse = "showcat/%d"
```

but the pagination doesn't work.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firsrly, I would use a forward slash instead of a dash:

`routes.cat2.route = "showcat/(\d+)/(\d+)"`

But, in either case, you're regex needs to know if the second statement doesn't exist, so:

`routes.cat2.route = "showcat/(\d+)(?:/(\d+))?"`

Or, with a dash:

`routes.cat2.route = "showcat/(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?"`

Note the question marks - indicated whether or not the item HAS to be be there.

Remember to set a default for the second parameter in your route:

`routes.cat2.route.defaults.2 = 1`